# Does the priority antenna direct a line straight toward the main board before sweeping clockwise?

Tags: robo-rally-2016

In Roborally 2016, page 4 of the rules states to

> ...imagine an invisible line pointing straight out from the antenna's dish. Once this line reaches the tied robots, it moves clockwise, and the tied robots have priority according to the order in which the line reaches them.

Their example claims Zoom Bot goes first as a result of this algorithm, yet Zoom Bot is first in the counter clockwise direction, unless I am misunderstanding.  Basically Zoom Bot is around the hour hand's "11:30" on the clock and Smash Bot is at "12:30".  Is the example wrong or does the antenna actually face a different direction than toward the board?

Comment: Link to picture of example please. We don't all have a copy of your version of the rules in front of us.

Answer (score 1):

The antenna can face in any direction. Here's a crappy image I tossed together in paint:
[image]

Assuming the antenna is facing the direction of the arrow priority would be resolved in the order indicated.

That said, I strongly suggest you ignore the priority rules (except in case of resolving ties) and resolve priority in the order: **Power ups -> Move 3 -> Move 2 -> Move 1 -> Backup -> Turns**. **Again**s resolve at the priority of the move they are copying. This will make your game go much faster, and won't appreciably change the game play... If you program spam cards, resolve them first, then take your turn as normal (this includes virus!)

Comment: Since damage goes to the discard pile 99% of the time it rarely matters... If it does matter, priority again is closest to the antenna.

Comment: Ahh. Yes! I'll revise the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the houserule clarification. There could still be priority conflicts. Say a robot is at position 4 and another at position 5. Both are facing position 1 and both have "Move 1". Who goes first? It definitely matters since one of them will be on the intended square and one of them will be pushed off. And of course, you still need the antenna for determining upgrade priority.