# Is priority reevaluated in between each robot's movement or do we keep how it was at the start of the register?

Tags: robo-rally-2016

In *RoboRally 2016*, we had a situation as follows. There were three robots on the board, which I have numbered 1 through 3 based on their priority and facing (thus "1→" is the first robot in priority order and is facing to the right).

[image]

Robot 1 did a "move 1" instruction and pushed Robot 2.

[image]

Note that of the two robots who haven't moved yet, Robot 3 is now closer to the Antenna than Robot 2. Do we keep the priority order, thus the one in the far right moves next?

Or do we immediately reevaluate the priority order as follows, thus the robot on the far left moves?

[image]

In other words, do we stick with priority that was set at the start of the register, or does it get reevaluated each time a Robot moves?

Comment: Using the priority antenna really slows the game down. I advise instead using it as a tiebreaker and instead start w/ faster actions. See [this questions](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/34131/does-the-priority-antenna-direct-a-line-straight-toward-the-main-board-before-sw) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: @aslum I've found that it isn't really slowing the game down for us, since we only calculate priority if it looks like there is actually going to be a conflict (i.e. two robots are going to ram into each other). If everybody is in their own section of the board, then we don't bother calculating priority and just all move our robots simultaneously.

Comment: I rarely play Roborally with less than 5 players, and it's already quite long... saving 20 seconds per turn is well worth it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules for Robo Rally can be found [here](http://media.wizards.com/2017/rules/roborally_rules.pdf).

On page 4 it says the following (emphasis mine):

> Determining Priority
>
> In ROBO RALLY, when a player has priority, it is that player’s turn. Rather than taking turns based on where they are sitting, players take turns based on where their robot is sitting on the board.
> **At any given time, the player whose robot is closest to the priority antenna has priority.** After that player takes their turn, the second closest player to the antenna has priority and takes their turn, and so on.

This means that priority is reevaluated after each player's turn.